# Jquery - возможно ли реализовать?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, надеюсь на вашу помощь.
[image]
Задача: есть картинки, две кнопки, и различный текст.
При нажатии на картинку она становится выделенной. При нажатии снова выделение снимается. При нажатии кнопки Clear все выделения снимаются. А при нажатии кнопки Check ниже появляется список определенных текстовых строк, причем если пользователь выделит другие изображения - появится другой список.
Можно ли данную модель реализовать на jquery? если да, то какие функции, селекторы использовать? Помогите новичку)

Answer (score 5):

Что именно у вас вызвало проблему? Вешаете на все картинки обработчик на событие [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), который будет [переключать класс](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) `selected`:

```
$('img.item').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

На `clear` [удаление всех классов](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) `selected`:

```
$('#clear').click(function() {
    $('img.selected').removeClass('selected');
}
```

На `check` [проход по циклу](http://api.jquery.com/each/) по всем элементам с классом `selected` и вывод текста, после чего сброс. Сам текст можно хранить в атрибуте картинки `alt` или [custom атрибуте из html5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    var list = $('<ul>').appendTo('#result');
    var selected = $('img.selected');

    selected.each(function() {
        var text = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('<li>').text(text).appendTo(list);
    });

    selected.removeClass('selected');
}
```

Визуальное выделение картинки осуществляется при помощи CSS:

```
img.selected {
    outline: 2px dotted #4c6aaf;
}
```

И еще посмотрите компонент [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#default) библиотеки Jquery UI.

Comment: Спасибо Илья за ответ,но у меня вот какая ситуация:

выделение я решил имитировать заменой одной картинки другой, также удалось повесить на кнопку Clear "снятие выделения", ну то есть скрытие картинки. 

Насчет текста ситуация немного сложнее, чем представили вы: это рецепты, которые можно приготовить из изделий которые на картинках. В одном рецепте используется несколько изделий. То есть, если выбраны некоторые изделия(изображения), то появится один список рецептов, а если пользователь выбрал другие изделия, то список рецептов будет другим.

Comment: Как я представляю, нужно создать какой-то массив элементов и из него делать выборки. Илья, вы не могли бы подсказать реализацию. залил код в файл.
http://zalil.ru/31444946